# Sign conventions

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, conventions, coordinate-systems

I had my first class of Applied Physics for Electrical engineering. And I am stuck in something very basic. The sign conventions. They are pretty confusing. The teacher said the position of origin din't matter. But some basic calculation I ran oppose that idea. I am attaching a picture. Please do tell me if something is technically wrong or am I too dumb?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The displacement in your first example should be negative, since you took origin to be *above* the final point and the acceleration to be negative going downwards.

Comment: I'm impressed that you could read that handwriting.

Comment: I teach disabled and handicapped children maths and physics. Their handwriting isn't good either. So, I can read the handwriting.